# MVC checkboxes & FormCollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

On a mass-edit form page I display about 50 objects that have some boolean properties as well. The controller receives a FormCollection with all values from the edit page.

```
    public void _EditAll(FormCollection c)
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var arrId = c.GetValues("channel.ID");
            var arrName = c.GetValues("channel.displayedName");
            var arrCheckbox = c.GetValues("channel.isActive");

            for (i = 0; i < arrId.Count(); i++)
            {
                Channel chan = db.Channels.Find(Convert.ToInt32(arrId[i]));
                chan.displayedName = arrName[i];
                chan.isActive = Convert.ToBoolean(arrCheckbox[i]);
                db.Entry(chan).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
     }
```

Now, for checkboxes, MVC creates hidden inputs on the form (otherwise "false" could not be posted back). In the controller, when receiving the FormCollection, this leads to the case that I receive an array of say

- 50 IDs,
- 50 names and ..
- 71 or so values for the checkboxes,

since the hidden checkbox has the same name as the visible one.

What's a good way to handle that and get the proper value of the checkbox?

Comment: Don't you wanna use your own viewmodel that checkboxes values will be automatically bound to?

Comment: You think that would take care of the checkbox-thingie? Hm I'll give it a try.

Comment: Couldn't get that working ( to pass a list of my entities with their correct state from the form to the controller ). Got that working only in case just one entity is being posted.

Comment: pls give me an example of your cshtml with a few controls you need to get values from

Comment: Don't bother, thanks for your help! Would you have a link to an example page with editing of multiple entites at once? I followed http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-lQr1zaVBEQ

Comment: let me try by myself...

Comment: so i made sample with array of business entities as viewmodel. Every entity has Id and State (for checkboxes). You (un)flag checkboxes on page, press Submit and your controller action gets this selection as an array of entities - is this what u need?

Comment: If by "this selection" you mean all entities including all of their properties like checkboxes for boolean properties, then - yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample for editing array of entities that have boolean field.

Entity:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool State { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Entity[] model = new Entity[]
        {
            new Entity() {Id = 1, State = true},
            new Entity() {Id = 2, State = false},
            new Entity() {Id = 3, State = true}
        };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Entity[] entities)
{
    // here you can see populated model
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

View:

```
@model Entity[]
@{
    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++ )
        {
            @Html.Hidden("entities[" + i + "].Id", Model[i].Id)
            @Html.CheckBox("entities[" + i + "].State", Model[i].State)
        }
        <input type="submit"/>
    }
}
```

The only tricky thing is html elements naming.
[More info](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) about binding arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort and the link, will try again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm converting all arrays containing checkbox-values:

"false" => "false", if not preceded by "true"